# Which firefox quirk causes this behavior and how can I recreate it in standards mode?

Tags: html, firefox, quirks-mode

For firefox, the following document renders differently in standards mode then in quirks mode. In quirks mode, the div fills the screen, however in standards mode it does not. I read through the MDN [quirks list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mozilla_quirks_mode_behavior) and couldn't seem to find a behavior to blame. While it'd be cool to know the quirk, my question is really **how can I replicate the quirks mode behavior in standards mode?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- remove doctype for quirks mode rendering -->
<head>
  <style>
  #test {
    height:100%;
    background:black;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test">
    content
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The relevant quirk is:

> There are a bunch of quirks to get percentage heights on images, tables, objects, and applets (etc.?) to "work" (the way they did in Netscape Navigator 4), even though CSS says that percentage heights should behave like 'auto' heights when the parent element doesn't have a fixed height. See bug 33443#c9. See also bug 41656 and its duplicates. Some of these quirks may cause other effects (see bug 54119).

The best replication of it that I can think of would be:

```
html,body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#test {
  height:100vh;
  background:black;
}
```

… or even just:

```
body {
    background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is acceptable, you can try another measure, for example, 'vh':

```
#test {
 height: 100vh;
 background: black;
}
```

vh - Equivalent to 1% of the height of the browser window.
vw - Equivalent to 1% of the width of the browser window.

Comment: This might be useful, but it certainly doesn't replicate the behavior of quirks mode in standards mode. Specifically, in my example, it overflows the page height because of the firefox default margins.